# add Context Menu in THREE.JS

Tags: three.js

i wan't to add context Menu when i right click on object 3D in scene

as this java script code

```
$(function(){
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one', 
    callback: function(key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
    },
    items: {
        "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
        "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
        "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
        "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
        "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
        "sep1": "---------",
        "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
    }
});

$('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked', this);
})
```

});

```
<div class="context-menu-one box menu-1">
<strong>right click me</strong>
```

this code i use it to create menu but can't find idea to make it relative to 3D object in scene

Comment: That's your job :) If you are having problems at some point, please be more specific what problem you need solved and what you have already tried.

Comment: i do it with Selector Class Name but how i can make it depended on mouse position in three.js scene

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert 3d coordinates to 2d screen (projected) coordinates.
Please have a look at [this post](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/78) for details and also the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534000/three-js-converting-3d-position-to-2d-screen-position).