# Converting World particle coordinates to Screen coordinates in Three.js using Projection

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am trying to get the screen coordinates for the vertices in a particle system within three.js. I have been trying to do this using the following code from [Three.js: converting 3d position to 2d screen position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534000/three-js-converting-3d-position-to-2d-screen-position):

```
function toScreenXY( position, camera, div ) {
    var pos = position.clone();
    projScreenMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
    projScreenMat.multiply( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
    projScreenMat.multiplyVector3( pos );

    var offset = findOffset(div);

    return {
        x: ( pos.x + 1 ) * div.width / 2 + offset.left,
        y: ( - pos.y + 1) * div.height / 2 + offset.top
    };
}

function findOffset(element) { 
    var pos = new Object();
    pos.left = pos.top = 0;        
    if (element.offsetParent)  
    { 
        do  
        { 
            pos.left += element.offsetLeft; 
            pos.top += element.offsetTop; 
        } while (element = element.offsetParent); 
    } 
    return pos;
}
```

I call this with the following information:

```
var test = toScreenXY(particleGeometry.vertices[i].clone(), camera, renderer.domElement);
```

However the coordinates that are returned do not match the screen coordinates.

There are other examples where this is discussed but they don't seem applicable ([Converting World coordinates to Screen coordinates in Three.js using Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586527/converting-world-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates-in-three-js-using-projection)) since the "object" referred to cannot be a Vector3D that defines the vertex.

What is an easy way to get the screen position of a particle in the particle system?