# three js show moving object hint box

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I create effect of HUD hint to moving object?

This should be a result:

[image]

Asteroid is moving in space, when i click on, it shows the hint box with information.

I experimenting with this example, http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html

but i don't know, if is it the correct way.

I need the hint in the same distance from the camera in each case, no matter how distanced is the asteroid. Always uncovered by another objects.

Comment: Try using an orthographic overlay as in [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html). Or overlay CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As WestLangley recommend, is needed to create new camera with view of elements on the screen.
3d to 2D camera is solved here [Three.js: converting 3d position to 2d screen position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534000/three-js-converting-3d-position-to-2d-screen-position)