# Converting a Vector3 point to screen space (Vector2) using Three.js [73]

Tags: three.js

I have initialised a perspective camera at a position looking at the origin (0,0,0). Reading around the most common solution to this I've found is the one described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412386/1330719.

From my understanding of the `project` method is, I should get a vector where the x,y coordinates are between -1 and 1. This doesn't seem to be the case at all and I end up getting coordinates that are completely out of bounds.

Furthermore, if the original vector point is at (0,0,0) I seem to get (NaN, NaN) back. If my camera is looking at position (0,0,0) I expect the Vector3 (0,0,0) to return (width/2, height/2).

In case it is needed, this is how I'm initialising my camera:

```
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10E5);

this.camera.position.set(0, 500, -500);
this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

Does anyone have a reason why this might not be working? Or alternatively a recommended way of mapping a Vector3 point to the screen space given a camera?

A jsfiddle of what I mean:
https://jsfiddle.net/m78wjLyc/

Comment: could you please post a jsfiddle of what you have right now? That would really help us to actually see the situation that you have trouble with.

Comment: your cameras' far plane (i.e. 10E5) is huge. Use something like 1000

Comment: @SalmonKiller I've added a jsfiddle for you to look at

Comment: @gaitat, my understanding is this is just a clipping plane and doesn't really matter (apart from regarding performance concerns)

Comment: it is a clipping plane but based on that value perspective computations are performed. The greater the value the bigger loss of accuracy on those computations.

Comment: ahh ok, useful to know thanks @gaitat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also use `camera.updateMatrixWorld(true)` before projecting.

Usually this is done automatically by *renderer*, but you don't use any, so the `camera.matrixWorld` stays untouched after you change the position, and makes the camera project things as if it was at the world origin.