# Cannot calculate 2D position from 3D co-ordinates

Tags: angular, three.js

I am selecting vertices from a point cloud using angular and three.js. I have been trying to label a selected vertex with its x,y,z information. I have been using these resources in my attempt:

1. [three.js Vector3 to 2D screen coordinate with rotated scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667395/three-js-vector3-to-2d-screen-coordinate-with-rotated-scene)
2. https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-align-html-elements-to-3d.html

and I can't get either to work as described.

My code currently is:

```
this.labels.forEach(element =>{
      const tempVertex = new THREE.Vector3(this.geometry.attributes.position.getX(element.index), 
                                          this.geometry.attributes.position.getY(element.index),
                                          this.geometry.attributes.position.getZ(element.index));


     
      let pointsMatrix = this.points.matrixWorld
      tempVertex.applyMatrix4(pointsMatrix);
      tempVertex.project(this.camera);

      let canvasBounds = this.renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();

      const x = Math.round( (   tempVertex.x + 1 ) * canvasBounds.width / 2 );
      const y = Math.round( ( - tempVertex.y + 1 ) * canvasBounds.height / 2 );

      element.label.style.transform = `translate(${x}px,${y}px)`;
    });
```

and it must be the calculation as I am always out by a similar amount:

[image]

I have tried to mix and match different ideas as I have attempted this and the screen shot is as close as I have got. I just don't understand the maths well enough to figure it out. I know plenty of people here do so can someone show me where I am wrong.

I think it could be something to do with using the pointCloud object to get the world matrix but that is my only geometry object. If it makes a difference no position is set when the div element is created.

```
 public createTextLabel(index: number){
    const elem = document.createElement('div');

    let x = this.geometry.attributes.position.getX(index);
    let y = this.geometry.attributes.position.getY(index);
    let z = this.geometry.attributes.position.getZ(index);

    elem.innerHTML = `X: ${x}<br> Y: ${y}<br> Z: ${z}`;

    this.labels.push({index: index, label: elem});
    this.hudContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(elem);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as close as I have managed to get it:

```
this.labels.forEach(element =>{
      const tempVertex = new THREE.Vector3(this.geometry.attributes.position.getX(element.index), 
                                          this.geometry.attributes.position.getY(element.index),
                                          this.geometry.attributes.position.getZ(element.index));

      let canvasBounds = this.renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();

      this.camera.updateMatrixWorld
      tempVertex.project(this.camera);

      tempVertex.x =  (   tempVertex.x + 1 ) * (canvasBounds.width + canvasBounds.left) / 2 ;
      tempVertex.y =  ( - tempVertex.y + 1) * (canvasBounds.height - canvasBounds.top ) / 2 ;
  
      element.label.style.transform = `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${tempVertex.x}px,${tempVertex.y}px)`;
    });
```

[image]

Two basic issues:

1. css was causing the second label to be lower in my previous screen shot. Needed to use view encapsulation: none to get my dynamic divs styled.
2. Wasn't including the gap measurement from the window to my canvas (not full screen)

Not perfectly even but good enough for now.