# Three.js - get screen position with no camera

Tags: math, three.js, 3d

I need to calculate screen position outside of Three, with with no camera present.

I know the object position, camera position and camera target

I've seen lots of instructions such as [three.js Vector3 to 2D screen coordinate with rotated scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46667395/three-js-vector3-to-2d-screen-coordinate-with-rotated-scene)

```
vector.project(camera);
vector.x = Math.round( (   vector.x + 1 ) * w / 2 );
vector.y = Math.round( ( - vector.y + 1 ) * h / 2 );
```

I understand Vector.project camera takes into account the camera settings, FOV etc I'd assume?

Vector3 has [projectOnVector()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.projectOnVector), does this do the same thing as vector3.project(camera) ?

Is there a way to calculate where the object would be on screen without being able to access the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `Vector3.project` takes into account the camera settings...

You need to calculate a projection matrix as you are trying to transform a position from world space to view space. This is a great little animation describing the journey that point will make: https://jsantell.com/model-view-projection/mvp.webm (lifted from this useful page: https://jsantell.com/model-view-projection/).

If you look in the three source code it will show you everything you need to do this. [Vector3.project](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/cbcea211a6aac54dff79741aec00f2e26725edb8/src/math/Vector3.js#L299) is just applying the two matrices from the camera:

```
return this.applyMatrix4( camera.matrixWorldInverse ).applyMatrix4( camera.projectionMatrix );
```

So how do you get these matrices? The project matrix is generated [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/cbcea211a6aac54dff79741aec00f2e26725edb8/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js#L177).

You can ignore the view, skew and zoom, so you just need near, far, aspect and fov.

```
updateProjectionMatrix() {

    const near = this.near;
    let top = near * Math.tan( MathUtils.DEG2RAD * 0.5 * this.fov );
    let height = 2 * top;
    let width = this.aspect * height;
    let left = - 0.5 * width;

    this.projectionMatrix.makePerspective( left, left + width, top, top - height, near, this.far );
}
```

If you need `makePerspective` it is [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/cbcea211a6aac54dff79741aec00f2e26725edb8/src/math/Matrix4.js#L772)

The `matrixWorldInverse` is just that... take your world matrix and inverse it. Three.js does it [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/cbcea211a6aac54dff79741aec00f2e26725edb8/src/cameras/Camera.js#L42).

This gives you your view matrix. So, view matrix multiplied with the projection gives you your screen space position... just like in a shader i.e:

`gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);`
I'm assuming your point is in world space so you can ignore the model part as this just takes you from model to world.

Comment: A stunning answer!