# Projecting a point from world to screen. SO solutions give bad coordinates

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to place an HTML `div` element over a three.js object. Most stackoverflow solutions offer a pattern similar to this:

```js
// var camera = ...

function toScreenXY(pos, canvas) {
  var width = canvas.width, height = canvas.height;

  var p = new THREE.Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
  var vector = p.project(camera);

  vector.x = (vector.x + 1) / 2 * width;
  vector.y = -(vector.y - 1) / 2 * height;

  return vector;
}
```

I've tried many variations on this idea, and all of them agree on giving me this result:

```js
console.log(routeStart.position); // target mesh
console.log(toScreenXY(routeStart.position));

// output:
// 
// mesh pos: T…E.Vector3 {x: -200, y: 200, z: -100}
// screen pos: T…E.Vector3 {x: -985.2267639636993, y: -1444.7267503738403, z: 0.9801980328559876}
```

The actual screen coordinates for this camera position and this mesh position are somewhere around `x: 470, y: 80` - I determined them by hardcoding my `div` position.
`-985, -1444` are not even close to the actual screen coords :)

Please don't offer links to existing solutions if they follow the same logic as the snippet I provided. I would be especially thankful if someone could explain why I get these negative values, even though this approach seems to work for everyone else.

Here's a couple of examples using the same principle:
[Three.js: converting 3d position to 2d screen position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534000/three-js-converting-3d-position-to-2d-screen-position)
[Converting World coordinates to Screen coordinates in Three.js using Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586527/converting-world-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates-in-three-js-using-projection)

Comment: When you make a statement regarding other solutions not working for you, you should link to those solutions to save time for those reading your question.

Comment: Those who are familiar with the topic will recognize the principle I described immediately. This seems to be a go-to solution for this problem. I would really appreciate the absence of non-essential comments. However, I have put in a couple of links to examples, you can check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I've figured out the problem myself! Turns out, you can't project things before calling `renderer.render()`. It's very confusing that it gives you back weird negative coords.
Hope other people will find this answer useful.

Comment: I'm glad to see you fix the issue yourself, but I'm pretty sure you don't need to call `renderer.render()`, calling  `camera.updateWorldMatrix()` and `camera.updateProjectionMatrix()` should suffice.

Comment: Hm, and I was wondering what `render()` could be doing to make projections work. I had a call to `camera.updateProjectionMatrix()`, but no call to `camera.updateWorldMatrix()`. Maybe that will do the trick :)